# Yahoo BOSS API - V1 -> V2

Tags: php, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-boss-api

I was using Yahoo BOSS API v1 and an URL I used got me backlinks for any site. Since the new update/upgrade to V2 the old URL is not working. Can anyone who has worked with V2 please help me out?
I found theold documentation very simple and organized really well but am lost with the new documentation.

Here is the old URL (which is not working anymore):

```
http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/se_inlink/v1/http://www.domain.com/index.php?appid=<appid>-&format=xml&omit_inlinks=domain
```

How would I have to modify this for the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and its not good. The se_inlinks APIs are being discontinued with version Here is the announcement from Yahoo.

In light of the announcements made this Friday June 8th by Yahoo! Search here (http://www.ysearchblog.com/2011/07/08/site-exploror-7-8-11/) , Inlink data will be shutdown on July 20th 2011 with the rest of BOSS v1 API. Customers can continue to query the YDN Site Explorer API (http://developer.yahoo.com/search/siteexplorer/) for such data until September 15th 2011.

I think it is eventually going away.